# Problem updating iPod Touch to iOS 5

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, ios

Using iTunes to upgrade the OS on a 4th generation iPod Touch, the update downloads but when it attempts to install it the process fails with the following message:

> The iPod "iPod Touch (4G)" could not be restored. An internal error occurred.

Any ideas what might cause this and how to avoid it?

Comment: Same thing here on my iPhone. I'm trying with another Mac right now.

Comment: I've had the same thing on my iPhone 4 (never jailbroken or anything). I read somewhere that the Mac should be running the latest OS update first, so I'm going to try updating to 10.7.2.

Comment: No luck with 10.7.2 with my 3GS. I don't now what's going on.

Comment: @Magnakai I'm on Snow Leopard (10.6.8), not Lion, but I did install the latest updates before trying to update the iPod.

Comment: I got it after several attempts. (iPhone 4, 10.7.2)

Comment: 10.7.2 is not required. iTunes 10.5 however *is* required. Once that dependency is satisfied, give it a try. If you still receive the error it is likely due to server overload. Give it a few hours and try again.

Comment: I noticed that it says "Verifying iTunes restore with Apple" right before it fails.  Perhaps the servers are overloaded with people updating at the moment?

Comment: After a couple more tries it has eventually got past the point where it was failing and is now in the process of updating the device.  @Patrick If you want to add your comment as an answer I will accept it as it seems to simply be a case of trying again until it works.

Comment: iTunes always logs an error when this fails - which error did you get? http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3694

Comment: Likewise, I've just finally succeeded in updating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is server overload. Either keep trying or wait till the traffic dies down a little.

[image]

You can [read more about it in this post](http://thenextweb.com/apple/2011/10/12/apples-ios-5-upgrade-servers-are-slammed-causing-3200-or-internal-error-update-issues/).

Answer (score 0):

iTunes always logs an error when this fails - which error did you get?

- [iTunes: Specific update-and-restore error messages and advanced troubleshooting](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3694)

Generic steps are worth checking if you haven't recently updated iTunes or the device.

- [iOS: Resolving update and restore alert messages](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1275)

Answer (score -1):

A possible reason is bad memory in the device. Newer versions of iOS tend to have a progressively larger memory footprint; if the larger size crosses a boundary in to the bad RAM area, the device will no longer boot up. I know of at least one iPhone owner with this unhappy result.

Comment: Occam's Razor...

Comment: @cksum, is a hardware problem the more complex or less complex explanation here?

Comment: @Daniel I'd say having a known server error on the day(s) a brand new iOS is loosed to the public (and the internet abuzz with similar occurrences) points more towards a "glitch in the Matrix" as opposed to some obscure issue with the devices memory. If my PC dies, I'm more inclined to see if the power cable came loose or that power is still being supplied before ripping it apart, testing the components. Any skilled technician always diagnoses a problem through a series of steps, incrementally working towards the more complex and rarer scenarios.